# Wordpress WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME values?

Tags: wordpress, url

I have a single WordPress installation and my website is at `example.com/site`. Everything works great.

I want to move my site to `example.com`. The instructions I got from my hosting company are described at the link https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/changing-the-site-url/

Do I simply need to edit my `wp-config.php` file to the following ?

```
define('WP_HOME','http://www.example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.example.com/site');
```

I have never done this before and not sure about the correct values for `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL`. Can you please help me. I don't want to break anything.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

you can get by following

```
define('WP_HOME','http://www.example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.example.com/');
```

`WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` must be same, you can also update your `siteurl`, `home` in your wp_options table

Comment: Actually, while `WP_HOME` & `WP_SITEURL` will be the same for ***most*** installations, there are configurations where these *must* be different. If you want your WordPress site to be accessed by typing `https://www.example.com` in the browser address bar, but you want your WordPress files located in a subdirectory `wordpress`, then the values *must be different*. The confusing part here is which one gets the value `https://www.example.com` and which one gets the value `https://www.example.com/wordpress`. One corresponds to database `wp_options.options_name` : `siteurl`, the other to `home`

Comment: could you remove the "must be the same"? it's not always the case as @SherylHohman mentioned.

Comment: And the docs explicitly state that there should be no '/' at the end.

Answer (score 3):

This answer merely extends Jothi Kannan's answer

If you want to move a WordPress site to a new domain you need to also consider Filepath names stored in your database may have absolute URLs linking to the previous domain name.

If you have access to run SQL (maybe through PHPMyAdmin, SQL tab) then you might want to consider running the following queries on your new domain to ensure all domains have changed.

Change the values in wp_options

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.old-domain.com', 'http://www.new-domain.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
```

Match and replace old site URL in `wp_posts` `guid`

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.old-domain.com','http://www.new-domain.com');
```

Match and replace old site URL in `wp_posts` `post_content`

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.old-domain.com', 'http://www.new-domain.com');
```

An alternative to this is using a plugin called [Duplicator](http://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) which is brilliant - but requires a certain level of system resources to function properly in my experience. Duplicator will take a dump of your website where you can deploy it to a different environment using an `installer.php` file.

It will import your database and change all the URLs for you as long as you specify the correct database credentials during installation.