# Difference between wp_siteurl and wp_home

Tags: wordpress

What's the actual difference between wp_siteurl and wp_home?

There's a related post which doesn't quite answer the question:

[Wordpress WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18336538/wordpress-wp-siteurl-and-wp-home-values)

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20294/whats-the-difference-between-home-url-and-site-url ?

Answer (score 11):

`WP_SITEURL` is a base url for resources: images, stylesheets, etc.

`WP_HOME` is where WP thinks site root url is (a base URL for links)

Example:
I had to integrate WP blog into my rails site, so i configured nginx to route all requests to `/blog` to WordPress, while all other requests went to my rails app. So I set `WP_HOME` to `mydomain.com` for WP links to work correctly, but I had to set `WP_SITEURL` to `mydomain.com/blog` for WP static assets to be found inside WP directory.

Comment: Interestingly a fresh installation of wordpress in its own folder will set both WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME to include this folder; they're the same

Answer (score 7):

Lets consider your awesome website's domain name is -

```
http://www.myawesomesite.com
```

Now one fine day you want to start a blog at this location -

```
http://www.myawesomesite.com/myniceblog
```

Now, answering your question -

```
WP_SITEURL = http://www.myawesomesite.com  //Your awesome wesbite's domain name
WP_HOME = http://www.myawesomesite.com/myniceblog  //Your awesome blog's homepage path
```

For further info - see [this Wordpress article](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_home-and-wp_siteurl).

Comment: this is incorrect. If you have wordpress files at `/myniceblog` and wish to have the blog sit at `/myniceblog`, both variables need to be the same `https://www.myawesomesite.com/myniceblog`