# Why wordpress redirecting me to the old website, after I migrated it to my local machine?

Tags: wordpress, redirect, migration, localhost

I migrated my wordpress website into my local machine, but it's redirecting me to the original ,-server one-, website, immediately after I opennig the local one.

**I try to describe what did I do as detailed as much I can:**

- First I got all wp files and copied-d it to my local XAMPP htdocs directory via SHH (FROM Linux Debian 10 - Apache 2 Webserver).
- After that I exported the database (exported to sql file format).
- I created the same database and user (with the same permissions as the server db user) in the local webserver
- Everything went successfully, but after i want to open http://localhost/ I got redirected to my old site like https://originalsite.com

**What did I tried to solve the problem:**

- I checked Apache, PHP and phpmyadmin version, but these are the same.
- I reinstalled XAMPP but that also didn't solve the problem.
- I checked `wp-config.php` but there aren't any options I've could been change, `php.ini` and `my.ini` both of them not gave me any alternative.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you change the blog URL in the settings, respectively in the Wordpress database?

Comment: One thing i forgot to mention is if I type localhost/wp-admin inside the URL bar it's also redirect me to the original site wp panel. But in that case I tried to open localhost/somethingdoestnotexist and it's appearing 404 but in the local site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `.sql` file you imported, find "`site_url`" and change it to localhost URL. Or you can define it in wp-config.php file as "`WP_SITEURL`"

Comment: I did it but nothing has changed. I tried WP_HOME too, but also didn't work.

Comment: Then try to go to your local address in incognito mode and clear browser cache and cookies. Besides, WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL are different, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25857114/difference-between-wp-site-url-and-wp-home

Answer (score 0):

You will need to manually go in Database and Replace LIVE site URL with the Local URL.
Something like:

```
https://originalsite.com/
TO
http://localhost/originalsite
```

Comment: I change every record what does contained the original site URL but also nothing has changed.