# Wordpress Html5Blank can't read my style.css after link update

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm struggling for days with that issue was wondering if maybe some over here can help me with that ?

I'm using the http://html5blank.com/ starter theme. I have been working on my development environment without any troubles. After updating my link for migration purpose via **wp-config.php** with that code :

```
define('WP_HOME','https://pleinsens.anatoletools.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://pleinsens.anatoletools.com');
```

After updating my link my site style-sheet doesn't apply anymore and i just can't get why.

My **header.php** containing the following code :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
        <title><?php wp_title(''); ?><?php if(wp_title('', false)) { echo ' :'; } ?> <?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>

        <link href="//www.google-analytics.com" rel="dns-prefetch">
        <link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/icons/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
        <link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/icons/touch.png" rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Barlow+Semi+Condensed:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Crimson+Text:ital,wght@0,400;0,600;0,700;1,400;1,600;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow+Condensed:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
        

        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>">
```

Anyone could help me figure this out ? I'm totally losing my head with that issue !

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The style.css would be being loaded by a function called wp_enque_script. We shouldn't see it in the header.php

Have you tried removing these lines?

```
define('WP_HOME','https://pleinsens.anatoletools.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://pleinsens.anatoletools.com');
```

The site's `WP_HOME` (where wordpress is located) might be different from it's `WP_SITEURL` (the url at which the site is accessed)

Because sub-domains are often hosted in sub-folders of their primary domain, try changing it to the following

```
define('WP_HOME','https://anatoletools.com/pleinsens');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://pleinsens.anatoletools.com');
```

Also, right click & view the source of the web-page, find the style.css that isn't loading & then double check the path/url that the link to the css file is pointing to matches what you expect it to & will load the style-sheet if pasted into your web-browser

Hope that helps! Here's a few more links that you may find helpful:

- [wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)
- [Difference between wp_siteurl and wp_home](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25857114/difference-between-wp-siteurl-and-wp-home)
- [WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_home-and-wp_siteurl/)